# Erase final member of std::set

Tags: c++, stl, set

How can I delete the last member from a set?

For example:

```
set<int> setInt;
setInt.insert(1);
setInt.insert(4);
setInt.insert(3);
setInt.insert(2);
```

How can I delete `4` from `setInt`?  I tried something like:

```
 setInt.erase(setInt.rbegin());
```

but I received an error.

Comment: Doh you're right I forgot set doesn't have random access iterator. Use `setInt.erase(std::prev(setInt.end()));`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
if (!setInt.empty()) {
    std::set<int>::iterator it = setInt.end();
    --it;
    setInt.erase(it);
}
```

By the way, if you're doing this a lot (adding things to a set in arbitrary order and then removing the top element), you could also take a look at `std::priority_queue`, see whether that suits your usage.

Answer (score 48):

in C++11

```
setInt.erase(std::prev(setInt.end()));
```

You can decide how you want to handle cases where the set is empty.

Answer (score 9):

**Edit: You should use [`std::prev`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev) as shown in [Benjamin's better answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8492704/430766) instead of the older style suggested in this answer.**

---

I'd propose using a different name for `rbegin` which has a proper type:

```
setInt.erase(--setInt.end());
```

Assuming you checked that `setInt` is not empty!

Btw. this works because you can call the mutating decrement operator on a temporary (of type `std::set<int>::iterator`). This temporary will then be passed to the erase function.

Comment: Cunning, because unlike `std::vector<int>::iterator`, there's no way that `std::set<int>::iterator` can be a pointer. It must be a class type, so temporaries must be decrementable.

Answer (score 4):

A bit less performant, but an alternative option:

```
setInt.erase(*setInt.rbegin());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete 4 instead of the last you should use the find method.
Depending on the use case 4 might not be the last.

```
std::set<int>::iterator it = setInt.find(4);
if(it != setInt.end()) {
  setInt.erase(it);
}
```

If you want to delete the last element use:

```
if (!setInt.empty()) {
  setInt.erase(--setInt.rbegin().base());
  // line above is equal to 
  // setInt.erase(--setInt.end());
}
```

---

While I was not sure if --*.end(); is O.K. I did some reading.
So the -- on rbegin().base() leads to the same result as -- on end().
And both should work.

Comment: setInt.[rend()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/rend/) returns an iterator that points before setInt.begin(), so it has nothing to do with the end of the set.

Comment: How is your proposal different from the one in the question, which as we already know doesn't work?

Comment: so I try again :-) with a lottle change. I should read before write :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the set is empty or not. If not, then get the last element and set that as iterator and reduce that iterator and erase the last element.

```
if (!setInt.empty())
 {
    std::set<int>::iterator it = setInt.end();
    --it;
    if(it != setInt.end()) {
    setInt.erase(it);
    } 
 }
```